# I have a json string . how can i break this in code , message and status code

Tags: javascript

// this is body.

OTP_BODY": "{"code":0,"status_code":"SUCCESS","message":"Generated One Time Password Successfully"}"

Comment: It would be useful to see a little more surrounding code.

Comment: You can use JSON.parse like this: var x = JSON.parse()

Answer (score 0):

```
 var jsonObject = JSON.parse(otp_body)
```

This will give you an object.
You can access code, status_code and message as
     jsonObject.code , jsonObject.status_code and jsonObject.message